# Combine these 2 subs in one excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty stuck with this VBA in excel, so I do need some help about merging these two subs.

```
Dim xRg As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Set xRg = Intersect(Range("E9"), Target)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value <= 5 Then
Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
"This is line 2"
On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
    .To = "Email Address"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "send by cell value test"
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Display 'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
Range("D9").Sort Key1:=Range("D100"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
End Sub
```

I hope you can help me with this because I am pretty much a newbie about it.
Thanks

Comment: You've got the same routine twice?

Comment: Assuming that there are no other calls to Mail_Small_Text_Outlook you can just delete the 4 lines starting with Call Mail_Small_Text_Outlook. If you want to tidy up a bit you can move the DIM statements up under the Private Sub Worksheet_Change line.

Comment: Just some code guidelines:
1. Indent your code to be better readable.
2. Remove "On Error Resume Next", excepts you really know it will throw an error and you would like to handle it in your code
3. What is this constant "5". Declare it as Const and give her a meaningful name
and as jamheadart said, there could not be two functions with the same name